# How to eliminate holes/bubble inside the volume of an object with blender

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, optimization

I’m a beginner and [I obtained my object, a mandible, from the CT-scan of a patient](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhulylwtceoj2az/mandible_Trim.mp4).

The problem is that inside of the bone tissue there are areas denser than others. To obtain the .stl file I have to decide which range of density value I want to include in my object. That fact results in an STL file with some holes bubble inside the volume.

To explain it better I could do an analogy: the volume that obtained is similar gruyere-cheese: outside the surface is smooth without any interruption inside there are a lot of bubbles/holes.

I can’t correct this problem during the transformation from CT to stl, so the question is: Do you know a method to fill the holes/bubbles? I don’t want to do it manually point by point because it will take hours.

I thought that I could make a hollow shell only of the external surface and fill it but I don’t know how to do it.

If you have other solution faster or smarter let me know.

Comment: You can try hovering one face of the external and press L (Select Linked). If you're lucky, only the faces you want to keep will be selected. Then I (invert selection), X (Remove Faces)

Comment: Also, the Voxel Remesher seems to get rid of the inside bubbles. In Object Data panel, under Remesh, select Voxel then adjust the resolution, press Voxel Remesh.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81677 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8822 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43150 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64754